# How to get comma seperated array from JSON response?

Tags: php

Im currently trying to get all the bitcoin prices from the last 30 days in a comma seperated string.

Im getting the price from coinbase api via https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/btc-eur/spot?date=11.03.2016 for example.

Now what I did is a for loop where it inserts every date of the last 30 days into the api link and gives me a long string with all prices. I would like to comma seperate each price in that string now.

Here the Code currently:

```
<?php

for($i=1; $i<=30; $i++)
 {
   $pricedates = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$i.' days',strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));



//Coinbase API for Historical Rates

    // Get data from Coinbase API
    $url        = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/btc-eur/spot?date=".$pricedates."";
    $btcdata    = @file_get_contents($url);
    $btcdata    = json_decode($btcdata, true);

    $btcprice = $btcdata['data']['amount'];

}

?>
```

**Sample data**

```
{"data":{"amount":"661.45","currency":"EUR"},"warnings":[{"id":"missing_version","message":"Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header","url":"https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"}]}
```

Comment: where's your problem?

Comment: You need to try first at least, there is no bug to solve SO is not for people to write code for you.

Comment: my problem is, that the string i get from "$btcprice" is NOT comma seperated. Its just a string with all bitcoinprices from the last 30 days sidebyside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `$btcprice = $btcdata['data']['amount'];` into `$btcprice[] = $btcdata['data']['amount'];` you'll end up with an array with all 30 values.

Then you can use `implode()` to glue the pieces of the array into a string.
`$btcprices_str = implode(',', $btcprice);`